# Table of contents: uncoloured but still clickable, with coloured internal links elsewhere

Tags: table-of-contents, texlive, texstudio

I am using the following:

```
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{41,159,49}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=darkgreen, linktoc=none, citecolor=darkgreen]{hyperref}
```

To colour links and urls. The line `linktoc=none` was intended to stop the table of contents from being coloured (didn't want a fully green table of contents). However, it also stops them from being clickable.

Is there a way around this?

Full document code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}



\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{subfiles}  %allows sub files to be included
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}  %extended support for graphics


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}     %Add colours to text
\usepackage{caption}   %customisable captions


\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{41,159,49}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=darkgreen, linktoc=none,      citecolor=darkgreen]{hyperref} 

\usepackage{titlesec}


%sets the font size for sections and subsections 
\sectionfont{\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont}


\begin{document}

\input{cover}
\tableofcontents

\input{intro}



\input{appendices}
```

\end{document}

The input documents contains nothing out of the ordinary, chapters, sections, so on.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us understand your exact problem by providing a complete compilable document so we can reproduce the error, including `\documentclass`, minimum necessary packages, `\begin{document}`, some text demonstrating your problem, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: @AndrewCashner i have no idea exactly which ones are necessary, but i'll try

Comment: I just meant the ones necessary to reproduce the problem. It's a good exercise to strip down to no packages or extra options and then add them in until you isolate what causes the error.

Comment: I understand that - i didn't add a lot of these packages, they came from a friends template, i didnt have time to learn everything from scratch, so im not sure what the inter-dependancies are like. either way i stripped most of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\hypersetup` just before `\tableofcontents` within a group:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{41,159,49}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=darkgreen, citecolor=darkgreen]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  {\hypersetup{linkcolor =black}
  \tableofcontents
  }
  \chapter{One}\label{chap:one}
  \ref{chap:one}
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Or better use `linktoc=page` so that page numbers become links.

[image]

Comment: Worked a treat. Went with messing with the hypersetup, as I wanted the contents names to be links. Thanks!